# Can I conditionally change what is returned by the_content() in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a child theme in Wordpress that needs some custom functionality (for an example, I want to show an author bio on things in the 'fiction' category, but not in the 'fiction-contest' category, though they otherwise look the same).

It seems that no matter how specific my templates are, eventually I run into one of two things:

```
the_content();
```

or

```
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
```

This is the part I want to have finer control over. Yet it seems I can only grab content as a big chunk. My workaround has been to style parts of the content as "display: none", depending on the template being used, but is there a way to conditionally change actual content returned by the above code? If so, how and where would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the_content() should return only the post contents.  The author information should not be included unless the author explicitly listed it within the post.

I believe you are looking for something along the lines of:

```
<?php

    // This array can contain category IDs, names, or slugs.
    // I went with an array for the ability to easily extend in the future.
    $cats_for_bio = array(
        "Fiction",
        "OtherCategory"
    );

    if ( in_category($cats_for_bio) ) {

        // You need to get the author id since we are outside of the loop.
        $authorID = $posts[0]->post_author;

        // Place your bio output code here as you please.
        // This example just grabs the author name and description.

        $authorName = get_the_author_meta("first_name", $authorID) . " ";
        $authorName .= get_the_author_meta("last_name", $authorID);

        $authorDesc = get_the_author_meta("user_description", $authorID);

        $authorBio = "<p><b>Author:</b> $authorName</p>/n";
        $authorBio .= "<p><b>Bio:</b> $authorDesc</p>/n";

        echo $authorBio;
    }
?>
```

Being that you are creating your own theme you can easily use the function get_the_content()... This will give you the content without echoing it... the downside of this is the filters that apply to the_content() are no longer applied.  You can get the content with the filters from the get_the_content() function by using apply_filters('the_content', $content) with $content being the return variable sent by get_the_content()

A third option which was previously mentioned is to create your own filter... this would be best done in a plugin and would be able to be applied to any theme you may use in the future.

Comment: This code would go in your single page template file where you would like your bio to be located.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide example code. If anyone wants to add answers to this question in the future, I would extend the question by asking "How could you conditionally add filters to a post?", but that really is another question.
This answer did the best job of explaining the actual process of adding conditional code to a post.

Comment: I find it easier to explain things with example code a lot of the time.

Comment: Dan, your answers showed that you know a lot more about Wordpress than I do, but didn't help me understand it better. I preferred this answerfor it's completeness, and for saying more precisely which template gets the code. I think this is the better resource for coders looking for an answer to this question. Your answer was first, but in fact it didn't 'click' until I saw the example code.

Answer (score 3):

Either:

1. Don't put the author bio in the post content (use a Custom Field for example) and display it when appropriate. You don't have to touch the content then.
2. Write a filter for `the_content` that changes its content when you want.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

Comment: For answer 1: It would be hard on the users to require them to use a custom field for something that is built into Wordpress. They would have to enter an author bio for each post, when there's a good author bio just sitting there in the database ready to be included.
For Answer 2: I will look it up. If I use my own filter, do I have to abandon the (very handy) get_post_format() filter, or write it into my filter? I've already told the users to use the custom post formats and it would be a shame to lose them.

Comment: If you mean the WordPress users, then why are you messing with the_content at all? What does displaying the bio have to do with how you display the post body?

Comment: Each post has an author bio attached, but some posts should not display it (typically where the author is just the publication's editor, and no authorship credit is necessary). Is there another way to attach an author bio, besides putting it in the post body?

Comment: By 'users', I mean the people who will be entering the content.

Comment: You write something `if (in_category('Fiction')) your_code_to_show_the_bio();` in the template.

Comment: Dan, I think you've given me far too much credit for my intelligence. Would I write that in the `content.php` template?

Comment: There is no `content.php` template in the [WordPress template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png). I don't know how that file is being used in your theme.

Comment: I guess I don't know how either, but when I open up a fresh copy of WP, there are several files in the 'twentyeleven' theme folder with 'content' in the name. (content.php, content-aside.php, content-gallery.php, content-single.php, etc.) In my child theme, I was trying to edit these. I thought they were the basic block a post's display was built on.

Comment: FYI, 'twentyeleven' is the parent theme I'm using. These 'content'-containing templates aren't present in 'twentyten', the other theme that comes out-of-the-box with a current WP download.
Sorry Dan, my question must not make much sense; this looks like one of those situations where I will have to answer the question myself to have enough WP knowledge to properly frame the question.